# Disable A Particular Key in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard, air, key

I know it should be simple, but I can't find a solution to this question.

How do i disable a particular key in AS3?

e.g. disable 'A' key, or 'Minus' key etc...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean disable it in a text field or something?

Answer (score 0):

for a `DisplayObject`: listen to `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` and if `event.charCode` is one you need to restrict call [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29)
for an input `TextField`: use [`TextField.restrict`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict) property